# Subversive choose Jira Issue upon commit

Tags: jira, subversive

Is there any Jira Plugin for Subversive that let's you choose the Jira Issue in the Subversive commit Dialog?

Backgound:
For now we write the Issue Number manually in each commit.
Problems:

- accidentally committing to the wrong Issue because Number was mixed up
- needs more time to switch from Jira to copy the number to Comit Dialog and paste it

Comment: I suggested to move this to serverfault. Sounds more like a sysadmins would have better advices for you.

Comment: This does appear to be on topic here, it does relate to tools used by programmers. However, if you don't get the answer that you need feel free to flag this for moderator attention and ask that it be migrated to a sister site like serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other possibilities are:

a) the JIRA Commit Acceptance Plugin
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/289

It allows to check if the issue does exists in JIRA and optionally if the committer has been assigned the issue.

b) TortoiseSVN Plugin
Allows to list issues (using a JIRA filter) and indicate for which issue the commit is being done
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/10017

Comment: a) is good to know! b) is pretty close :) is there anything without the need to install .NET Framwork?

Comment: I installed b) once just to try out, but we settled down using the connector for eclipse.

Comment: a) is the answer to my question, however i forgot to mention the importance of a Eclipse Plugin. So i'll try out the Eclipse Connector

Answer (score 3):

[atlassian connector for eclipse](http://www.atlassian.com/software/ideconnector/) provides a way to import JIRA data into eclipse. Not sure if it lists the issues on commit screen. However, you won't have to switch windows at least.

Comment: The link says: No longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Although I strongly believe that the commit-to-issue linking should be handled in the server-side (not by trusting the SVN client), the *JIRA Commit Acceptance Plugin* mentioned in Francis' answer is not maintained for several years.

Earlier this year we analyzed its shortcomings, and built a new JIRA add-on to tackle the same problem using all modern JIRA features, like:

- JQL for super-flexible conditions
- P2 framework for fast installations and upgrades without JIRA restarts
- Standard REST API

(The full comparison is available [here](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/alternatives#jira-commit-acceptance-plugin).)

The new add-on called [Commit Policy](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.jira-commit-policy-plugin) is available from the Atlassian Marketplace!

*(Diclr: I'm a developer working on both the old and the new add-ons.)*